# Select a document with the begin of string value like a number

Tags: mongodb

I have a field with a number and unit.

```
db.createCollection("test")
db.test.insertOne({"curVal":"100°"})
```

I would like to select document with curVal > 50.

I found a solution but I'm not happy with it.

```
# 1. match record with curVal
# 2. add field _double_curVal with result of regexFind
# 3. convert the _double_curVal.match to double
# 4. filter curVal > 50
db.test.aggregate(
[
    {"$match":{"curVal":{"$exists":true}}},
    {"$addFields":
        {"_double_curVal":
            {"$regexFind":
                {"input":"$curVal",
                 "regex":"[0-9]+"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {"$project":
        {"_double_curVal":"$_double_curVal"
        }
    },
    {"$project":
        {"_double_curVal":
            {"$convert":{"input":"$_double_curVal.match","to":"double"}
            }
        }
    },
    { "$match":
        { "_double_curVal":{"$gte":50}
        }
    }
])
```

Can you propose a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not say this is better solution but you can try, do all operations in a single `$match` stage with `$expr`,

- `$let` to declare vars for `curVal` to find number using `$regexFind`
- `$toDouble` convert `curVal.match` string to number
- `$expr` to match expression matching condition with `$gte`

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                curVal: {
                  "$regexFind": {
                    "input": "$curVal",
                    "regex": "[0-9]+"
                  }
                }
              },
              in: { $toDouble: "$$curVal.match" }
            }
          },
          50
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VGcvTge1qyO)